# All duplicates not being removed as it makes row 1 an immune header row

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, pandas

All duplicates not being removed as it tends to ignore row one and deems it a header row.

https://ibb.co/b4GvJG

I am attempting to delete duplicates for all the columns.  This is achieved suffice for one pair of duplicates in the first row.  In this case the b become b.1.  There are also numbers in Column A though this is not affecting the job thus far and is more a nuisance than job breaking. As we deal with large number of excel spreadsheets, missing one duplicates for lots of files really adds up.

I assume by adding a header column or by removing the header row, then the data can be all duplicated rather than ignoring first row.
To resolve this I have tried to add headers, drop the level and remove start row:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Heading': data})
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', startrow=2)
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', startrow=2, header=False)
raw_data = {'0': ['first_name', 'Molly', 'Tina', 'Jake', 'Amy']}
#df.columns = df.columns.droplevel(0)
#df.to_excel(writer, header=None,index=False)
#df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=[df.columns[6]])
```

Thus far, I have not had any success and the issue persists.

Standard code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel("C:/Documents/Ha.xlsx", sheetname=0)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('C:/Documents/Ha.xlsx')
import xlsxwriter
import pandas as pd

df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', startrow=2, header=False)

df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=[df.columns[2]])

writer1 = pd.ExcelWriter('C:/Documents/Book2.xlsx')
df.to_excel(writer1,'Sheet1')
writer.save()
print(df)
```

Comment: The original sheet starts at row 2, however Pandas tends to automatically put  first cells with text and assumes that row from former is a header.  One way to get around is it to label csv and excel files though considering the load of excels I have not very viable.

Comment: df = pd.read_excel("C:/Documents/Ha.xlsx", sheetname=0, header=None) may resolve the issue.  Data above, gaps, and data in Column A.  Not perfect but definitely workable.  Will do further testing.